# F.lux GUI doesn't open, unable the modify timezone/location

Tags: uninstall, configuration

I installed F.Lux while living in Asia. It just asked about my timezone and it ran. It worked, but I had no access to the gui, which I guess was fine at the time.

Now I'm back in Europe and this is killing my eyes. I have the flux installed as per their official way, nothing happens when I press the app. Same thing in cmd - if I write `fluxgui` it just says `fluxgui is already running, exiting` but it's still running and I can't close it.

I've tried purging and installing it again from the repository. Same thing happens. It just runs automatically at the Asian timezone.

Comment: FYI I've tried purging and installing it again from the repository.. same thing happens. It just runs automatically at the asian timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried F-lux before moving the Redshift and I just found my settings. You can edit them in graphical [`gconf-editor`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gconf-editor/) or manipulate them with [`gconftool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gconf2/):

```
$ gconftool --all-entries /apps/fluxgui
 latitude = 50.9848
 autostart = 1
 longitude = 11.0299
 colortemp = 1
$ gconftool --get /apps/fluxgui/latitude
50.9848
```

You could unset a particular key from terminal with `--unset` or unset all keys with `--recursive-unset`, which should stop it from running or enable you to change the configuration through the GUI. More parameters on the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/gconftool.1.html).

I also looked at the package and found that `xflux` is, similar to what has been brought up again in recent news about F.lux on other platforms, only provided as a **compiled binary in the source package** (it's closed source). I recommend you move to [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) which has seen lots of improvements in recent versions and supports multiple monitors.

Comment: Redshift doesn't work for me. It flickers on/off constantly which is a pain - been with f.lux purged, which I otherwise suspected was the conflict

Comment: Can I ask how I do this in practice? Should I `sudo apt-get install` the gconftool/editor from somewhere, and then locate the file itself? Not sure what the process is exactly. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer with links to the packages.

Comment: Thank you! I reset it with the command you provided, and got `fluxgui` again. Now it actually started and I could input my data again. Cheers.